# How can I deploy an Azure Logic App Standard from one resource group to another?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Need to create a new app service plan and storage account along with the deployment of azure standard logic app

I tried using export template but couldn't find anything related to the workflow I've created.

Comment: Did you tried anything? it would be great if you provide more details like your approach and blockers. Then only community members can help.

Comment: I tried exporting the template but couldn't find my logic app/workflow actions in the template . This is the first time working on standard logic apps.  Need to know what's the standard procedure !

Answer (score 0):

> How can I deploy an Azure Logic App Standard from one resource group
> to another?

**You can use Azure portal or Visual studio code to deploy logic app from one resource group to another resource group.**
Below is the process for Azure portal:

- Go to the overview of standard logic app in portal,
  [image]
- Click on **move** beside resource group as shown above. This will move logic app from one resource group to other resource group.
- Once you click on move, you will be navigated to a new window for selecting target resource group.
  [image]
- Once you click on next, it will validate and create logic app on mentioned resource group.
- As shown in below images you can successfully moved to another resource group.
  [image]
  [image]

**Visual studio Code Process:**

- Follow this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code) to setup Vs code to create and deploy logic apps.
- Once you have created logic app, you can use export logic app to download to your local or you can deploy to another resource group.
- I have created a sample logic app in vs code as shown below,
  [image]
- Go to Azure on VS code and select deploy to logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- This will help you to deploy logic app to the required resource group.

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/set-up-devops-deployment-single-tenant-azure-logic-apps?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Is there any other way we can deploy using ARM template along with creating a new app service plan and storage account for the deployed Logic app[standard] in the new resource group ?

Comment: @Mahesh Yes ,You can. Refer these [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview) [documents](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/design-arm-template-to-deploy-standard-logic-app-to-private/ba-p/3730645)